# How to limit the number of rows displayed in a picker view?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

The `UIPickerView` by default displays 7 rows (1 active, 6 inactive) which takes about 210px height including the vertical padding.

[image]

How can I display only 2 inactive items (1 above and 1 below the active item) to limit the height of the picker?

[image]

I can use `UIPickerViewDataSource` extension to define the total number of rows and columns. What I need to limit the number of inactive rows to reduce the element height and the overal visual complexity of my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `UIPickerView` height, so it only displays 3 elements. I prepared a simple demo, where we set the `UIPickerView` height to a constant and use `UIPickerViewDelegate`'s `rowHeightForComponent` function to set the row height to the `UIPickerView` height divided by the desired number of rows.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    private let pickerViewHeight: CGFloat = 150
    private let numberOfVisibleRows: CGFloat = 3 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let picker = UIPickerView()
        picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(picker)

        picker.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self

        picker.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        picker.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pickerViewHeight).isActive = true
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return "Row \(row)"
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return pickerViewHeight / numberOfVisibleRows
    }
}
```